# Python: Kivy module doesn't show widget

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to use kivy to create a simple interface; I'm following the documentation but I don't understand why I can create only a blank window, while the widgets don't show up.
I'm on Ubuntu 20.0.4

I created two files:
main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MainWidget(Widget):
    pass


class GameApp(App):
    pass


GameApp().run()
```

game.kv

```
#:kivy 2.0.0

<MainWidget>:
    Button:
        text: "Hello"
        size: "100dp", "80dp"
        pos: "100dp", "200dp"
        color: 0, 0, 1, 1
    Label:
        text: "Hello2"
        size: "100dp", "80dp"
        pos: "200dp", "300dp"
        color: 1, 0, 0, 1
```

This is the terminal's reply

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/marco/.kivy/logs/kivy_21-08-18_60.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/home/marco/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15) 
[GCC 9.4.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.3 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 20.2.6'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'nouveau'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'NV126'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 3
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.30'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Kivy documentation

> To initialize your app with a widget tree, override the build() method in your app class and return the widget tree you constructed.

So in order to show your MainWidget, your GameApp class which is inhereted from the kivy App-class has to override the build() method and return an instance from MainWidget like so:

```
class GameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWidget()
```

Comment: I have tried it but it doesn't work, I think the problem is connected to the file .kv, because i noticed that using     `def build(self): return Label(text='Hello world')`, it shows the text